# Abandoned vigrahas

Tags: temple, puja, idols

Namaskaram to all !

I am planning to set up a temple inside my house. I wish to do prana-pratishta of the vigraha, offer naivedya twice everyday, recite sahasranam etc. The deity is Venkateswara.

But I fear that I might not be able to correctly follow all the procedures. More than that, I am afraid that my following generations will not take to worship.

1)Are there any curses associated with the abandonment of puja and rituals to such vigrahas?
2) Are there any curses associated with improper/unsatisfactory worship of vigrahas?
3) What if I build a temple, offer worship to the vigraha until I die, and after my death, it is abandoned/not visited/no worship offered by my sons/upcoming generations? Will I dwell in hell?

Also, I have heard that improper worship of vigrahas might spell doom for the entire family.

Kindly help.

Thanks and Regards